# Translate "-it" argument from docker run to docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working on creating a docker-compose.yml for a docker image that runs with the "-it" option. How could I recreate that command in the yml?

Comment: look at the "stdin_open" and "tty" options in the docker compose reference documentatiom: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a one-off command on a service, you can use `docker-compose run <service> <command>` (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpuset-domainname-entrypoint-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir)), which will start a new container, based on the configuratiin set in the docker-compose file. For example `docker-compose run db bash`.

Note that you can also just use `docker`